# Saving text file content to a linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to save the contents of a word file line by line into a LinkedList. 
What am I doing wrong? The console is showing that it is definatley reading the file but not saving its contents?

```
public class SpellCheck {

LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList();

boolean suggestWord ;

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the spellchecker");

    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    try {
        File f = new File("input/dictionary.txt");
        FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

        String line = null;
        String word = new String(); 
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  
        {      
                list.add(word);
                word = new String();
           }
         reader.close();

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

    }

}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `word` which is an empty string instead of adding line which you read from file:

```
String word = new String(); 
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  
{      
     list.add(word);
              ^^^^^
     word = new String();
}
```

It should be:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {      
      list.add(line);
}
```